# Trouble with the Parse tutorial (Android)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to use Parse to program an Android app. I am following the tutorial on this link: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide

While the tutorial/guide is fairly straight forward, I am having problem with a query to the Parse database. The specific part of the guide is: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-retrieving

Code from relevant section:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>(){ 
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e){ 
        if (e == null){ 
        // object will be your game score 
        } else { 
        // something went wrong 
        } 
    } 
});
```

I am using Android Studio 1.0.1, and the error I am getting is:

> Class 'Anonymous class  derived from GetCallback' must be either be
>   declared abstract or implement abstract method 'done(T,ParseException)
>   in GetCallback

Any help or suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

Turns out it was just my database on Parse.com that was somehow corrupted... Creating a new database fixed it, for whatever reason. I do however have another problem. I can debug inside the done function, and the object contains all the information. However, I cannot extract it outside the done function. How is that done? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you add `@Override` to the `done` method?

Comment: Same error on GetCallback, but on @Override it says: Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: What do you wanna debug in the done function , the object ??

Comment: No, I debugged in the done function to see if 'object' contained any information, which it did, however I want this information (or the object) outside of the done function.

Comment: My IDE didn't import `com.parse.ParseException`, which caused that same error to occur, hopefully this will help someone else

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. In my case I auto imported wrong library:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
```

instead of

```
import com.parse.ParseException;
```

Just check your import.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. the done function is the callback method for when the query has been completed. If you debug your code you'll notice that it steps over the function because it is called asynchronously, meaning that the application wont wait for it to complete.

Once the query returns you are meant to check if there has been an error and then do whatever you need to once you have retrieved the parse object.

Comment: Then how do I either make it wait for the object to be retrieved from Parse or retrieve it later? I feel like the Parse website is skipping out a bit on that, or am I overlooking it - I tried to follow the documentation linked above as close as possible.

Comment: For every function there tends to be a corresponding synchronus method i.e find findInBackground (check parse the actual format). Its not advised to use the synchronous methods as your UI will freeze while it waits for the query to finish. I'm not sure by what you mean by 'retrieve it later'. You retrieve the data in the callback function (done), then you do whatever you want to it inside the done function. I imagine anything you wanted to do outside of the done function can be done inside it

Comment: I can't do whatever I want to do inside the done function. Say I want to change a textView so that it is equal to a string value stored within the object. Now, I can see through debugging that the object does indeed contain the string, I just can't extract it - I can't make the done function change the textView properties. That is why I wanted to extract the object out of the done function, because outside of the done function I can do the textView change anyway.

Comment: Yes you can. I suggest you go look at contexts and retrieving them in certain situations.